# Show that the series converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

You have the sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, so that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, you have to 
$$x_ {n}:= \ln\frac{n + 1}{n}$$
 Find an explicit formula for the partial sums of the series generated by $(x_{n})_{n \in\mathbb{N}}$ and determine if the series converges.

**My development**
I'm supposed to find a formula that generalizes the sum, so what I did is
\begin{align*}
S_{n}&=a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+\cdot+a_{n-1}+a_{n}\\&=S_{n-1}+a_{n}
\end{align*}
thus,
\begin{align*}
a_{n}&=S_{n}-S_{n-1}\\&=\ln\frac{n+1}{n}-\ln\frac{n}{n-1}\\&=\ln\frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{n^{2}}
\end{align*}
and you should determine if $ \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln\dfrac{(n-1)(n + 1)}{n ^ {2}} $ is convergent, right?

Comment: No. For this series $$S_n=x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_n=\sum_{k=1}\ln\frac{k+1}k.$$ You are still expected to use the rule: sum of logarithms if the logarithm of the product.

Comment: The $S_n$ you have calculated, by contruction, is equal to $x_n$.

Comment: But, did you search? I'm fairly sure this series has been studied on our site earlier.

Comment: and excuse the obtaining of the partial sums of the series generated by $ (x_ {n}) $, if it is ok?

Comment: Thank you! but I have no problems for convergence, which is not how to obtain the explicit form of the partial sums.

Comment: @moisesushiña the answers there derive the explicit form for the partial sums.